# Subspace of $L^2[0,1]$ which is dense in $L^p[0,1]$ for $1\le p<2$ but not in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am stuck on this problem since many times, based on the hint also I am totally clueless about how to construct g.
So can anyone give me a minor hint how to approach this, Really I mentioned such a word minor because I do not want much spoiler for this, as this problem seems challenging so I want to do it by myself with taking some minor hint?[image: 1]

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: Suppose $g \in L^2$ but $g \notin L^p$ for all $p<2$.  Then of course $g^\perp$ is not dense in $L^2$.  Is it dense in $L^p$ for $p<2$?

Comment: @GEdger $L^2[0,1]\subset L^p[0,1]$ for $1\le p<2$

Comment: you want $g \not\in L^p$ for all $p>2$.

Comment: @Dunham I find it on internet.

Comment: @daw  I want a $g\in L^2[0,1]$ such that there is a sequence of $L^2$ functions say $f_n$  that does not converges to g in $\|.\|_2$ norm but in $\|.\|_p$ norm for all $1\le p<2$. Also $\{f_n\}$ should be in the orthogonal complement of $span\{g\}$. That means $\langle f_n,g \rangle=0$.